# Fetch api data from Node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, api

I have odbc connection to database on Node JS.

```
var express = require('express');
var odbc = require('odbc');
var app = express();
var connectionString = 'Dsn=xxx;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx';


app.get('/query/:table', function (req, res) {
    var table = req.params.table;
    //console.log('User is accessing : ' + table);
    var connection = odbc.connect(connectionString, (error, connection) => {
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM " + table + "", (error, result) => {
            if (error) { console.error(error) }
            var json = JSON.stringify(result);
            res.send(json);

    });
});

});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
app.listen(80, function () {
    console.log('Application listening on port 80');
});
```

on localhost/query/colli my output is :

*[ { "MATRK1": "0000019863", "FLG1K1": "S" }, { "MATRK1": "0000019864", "FLG1K1": "S" }]* (and a lot of more rows)

My index.html looks like this :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"
        integrity="sha256-BTlTdQO9/fascB1drekrDVkaKd9PkwBymMlHOiG+qLI="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
function getElement(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

    fetch('http://localhost/query/colli')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
            const data = res;
            document.write(data)
            getElement('name').innerHTML = 'Name: ' + data;
        });
</script>
<div>
    <p id="name"></p>
</div>
<body>
</body>
```

But i am receiving :

*[object Object],[object Object]* result

What am i doing wrong please? I want to fetch data from Node into HTML.

Thanks very much for your time :)

Comment: Couple of things: at node end simply doing `res.json(result)` should send back a json response. At client html side u don't need two `.then` and `res.json()` simply read the `fetch` response, console it and see what data u require from that.

Comment: Thank you, i fixed it, but right now im receiving "Name: undefined" according to the comment bellow

Comment: Can you show/update the question with what `console.log(data)` looks like?

Comment: I answered bellow :)

Answer (score 0):

As `data` is a JSON object you can't do `getElement('name').innerHTML = 'Name: ' + data;`. You will have to get a specific key from your object leading to the value you are looking for.

Comment: But when i try to go deeper like this : ```getElement('name').innerHTML = 'Name: ' + data.MATRK1;``` Iam receiving "Name: undefined"

Comment: Try to use ```console.log(data)``` to see what you have before using it in your code

Comment: Try something like that on fetch answer: ```response.json().then(function(data) {
});```

Answer (score -1):

depending on your console.log, call the get method

```
  getElement('name').innerHTML = 'Name: ' + data[0].MATRK1
```

since data is array of objects, we need to access each object by its index, and each object has the key MATRK1 in it, so we access it using data[0].MATRK1

Comment: (index):13 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.get is not a function
    at (index):13

Comment: depending on your console.log, where u said im getting somewhere, do this
console.log(data[0]). since your data is an array, or try logging everything, data.forEach(i => console.log(i)}

Comment: Foreach log : `{MATRK1: "0000019863", FLG1K1: "S"}
MATRK1: "0000019863"
FLG1K1: "S"
__proto__: Object`

Comment: Thank you very much :) right now ill fit it in the table and it will be solved :)